# How did Carrie get from the cave to the Colony?

Tags: girl-in-the-woods

Near the end of *Girl in the Woods*, we see that the members of the cult managed to rescue Carrie and bring her back to the Colony, and she appears mostly unharmed (able to stand and walk, at least). However, last we saw her, she was at least hundreds of feet underground, unable or unwilling to move, and a cave had just collapsed on her head, dumping a whole river full of water on her.

How did she survive this, and how did the cult members manage to find her to bring her back to the colony? Did it have something to do with the Gehenna parasite?